Kerberoc map root/super user to a NIS account?
Here is the scenario.

I have a NIS account a CentOS host with a valid kerberos tkt/principal, which controls access to various kerberized mounts.
Local root/super user does not have kerberos tkt and hence cant access these mounts, which am trying to fix.

Can root user be mapped at the client side ( I dont have NFS server root/super user privileges at the ) by using auth_to_local rules in the krb.conf at the client side, so that root/super user also can access those mounts ?


What OS is the client side running? 2) How did you provide tickets for the initial mount? (The initial mount is done as root and requires tickets, so if you have the share mounted, then you probably have solved the problem somehow already?)

